# Scala sequence groupBy then map different functions to groups then flatten it

Tags: scala, sequence

Generally i has list of elements like that

`List(A1, A2, B1, A3, B2, B3, B4, A4, ...)`

All elements can be divided by two groups:

1. `A` group
2. `B` group

For each group i want to applay different functions:

1. for `A`: `myFunc1`
2. for `B`: `myFunc2`

And then collect parts of list into one list.

I gain that by this code:

```
  myList
    .groupBy(p => p.sourceId < 0 && p.signerId.isEmpty)
    .flatMap(tuple => tuple match {
      case tre if tuple._1 =>
        tuple
          ._2
          .map(myFunc1)
      case fls @ _ =>
        tuple
          ._2
          .map(myFunc2)
    })
```

But this code looks ugly because each time i need to get value like `tuple._2` of any keys (`true`/`false`) from `Map` which i has from `groupBy`.

What the good and less verbose way of doing that work: divide sequence by 2 groups + map different functions for it + flatten groups to list?

---

### Some variants of answer

[by Ethan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60442656/4367350) using `map` + `if/else`:

```
myList.map(p =>
  if (p.sourceId < 0 && p.signerId.isEmpty)
    myFunc1(p)
  else
    myFunc2(p)
)
```

like [by Ethan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60442656/4367350) but using `match/case` instead `if/else`:

```
vkPosts.map({
  case p1 if p.sourceId < 0 && p.signerId.isEmpty => myFun1(p1)
  case pN if p.sourceId > 0 => myFunN(pN)
  case pUndefined @ _ => myFun2(pUndefined)
})
```

Comment: Do you really need to get the two groups first to then map it? What about a function that behaves differently given its input, so you only need on `map` or `flatMap`. If not, will you always have two groups or do you want a generic approach for any number of groups?

Comment: Function that behaves differently for inputs can be more complicated as i think - it is good to divide it like in my `func1` for `A` and `func2` for `B` and ... `funcN` for `N`, so generic approach for any number of groups is better. Its unneeded to save groups and simply need to map `funcN` to relevant `N`. Also i got some answer (it's marked) - if you can advice some more scalish - welcome!)

Comment: you accepted exactly what I proposed. Just one function that works for all types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you don't actually need to group, you can just have a single map with the if statement in it. Something like

```
myList.map(p =>
  if (p.sourceId < 0 && p.signerId.isEmpty)
    myFunc1(p)
  else
    myFunc2(p)
)
```

In other cases, you might want to split the collection in two. There's a `partition` function for that. You can do something like

```
val (type1, type2) = myList.partition(p => p.sourceId < 0 && p.signerId.isEmpty)
type1.foreach(p => s"Type 1: $p")
type2.foreach(p => s"Type 2: $p")
```

Comment: ah, really) don't think about it)) thx. also we can use here match/case for more then 2 variants, add it to my question

Answer (score 1):

If you need all the `myFunc1()` results grouped together and separate from the `myFunc2()` results.

```
val (a,b) =  myList.partition(p => p.sourceId < 0 && p.signerId.isEmpty)
val rslt  = a.map(myFunc1) ++ b.map(myFunc2)  //or something like this
```

---

If you're on Scala 2.13.x you can `pipe` them together.

```
import scala.util.chaining._

myList.partition(p => p.sourceId < 0 && p.signerId.isEmpty)
      .pipe(t => t._1.map(myFunc1) ++ t._2.map(myFunc2))
```

Comment: ok, would know it, but interesting another: when i try to do some workaround with `partition` i try to find some way writing map for each element of `tuple2` like that:
`myList.partition(???).map(map(myFunc1),map(myFunc2))`, also try another variants but no gain success.. is there any variants to got `partition` result as `tuple` and perform for each element its own map?

Comment: interesting method do not see it before. thx. in real i try to do like that in first time when solve the problem